# Não retorna os dados da tabela do banco de dados PDO

Tags: php

[image]
Não está retornando o array com os dados da tabela, de primeira eu achei que a tabela estava vazia, mas NÃO está!, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: A sintaxe da sua dsn está errada, é "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbphp7", e não desta forma que vc fez

Comment: @jonas2591 Provavelmente retornará apenas o primeiro registro encontrado na tabela de acordo com o critério passado na query, isso que está ocorrendo??

Comment: @jonas2591  uma sugestão para conseguirem te responderem mais rápido sobre alguma dúvida e colocar o código na pergunta, nessa vc colocou o print do código.

Comment: Eu conheço esse código, é de uma videoaula do Curso de PHP Completo da HCode, se voltar a vídeoaula e prestar atenção no código vai ver onde está errando.

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão de código:

```
<?php

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbphp7';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';

    try{
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

***usando o FetchAll***

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios ORDER BY deslogin");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

***usando o Fetch***

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios ORDER BY deslogin");
$stmt->execute();

while ($linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($linha);
}
```

Observe a diferença entre eles.

[FetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php) vs [Fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo do site oficial do PHP:

```
<?php
    /* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
    $sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
    $red = $sth->fetchAll();
    $sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
    $yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php